# Create a JSON structure that will capture some information about Subjects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to fill a JSON file with subject and the information for the subjects, I want to know if I have done it well based on the requirements that were asked.

[What I had to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkS1a.png)

**What I have done:**

```
{
"Subjects": [
   {
      "Code": "01",
      "Semester": "1",
      "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
      "Professor": "Profesor 1",
      "Credits": "7",
      "Grade": "9",
      "Keywords": "jquery",
      "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
   },

   {
     "Code": "02",
      "Semester": "2",
      "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
      "Professor": "Profesor2",
      "Credits": "6",
      "Grade": "9",
      "Keywords": "javascript",
      "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
   },

   {
    "Code": "03",
     "Semester": "7",
     "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
     "Professor": "Profesor 3",
     "Credits": "6",
     "Grade": "7",
     "Keywords": "php",
     "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
  },

  {
    "Code": "04",
     "Semester": "2",
     "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
     "Professor": "Profesor 4",
     "Credits": "4",
     "Grade": "6",
     "Keywords": "java",
     "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
  },


  {
    "Code": "05",
     "Semester": "4",
     "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
     "Professor": "Profesor 5",
     "Credits": "4",
     "Grade": "7",
     "Keywords": "css",
     "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
  }

]
```

}

Have I done this correctly or do I need to make more changes to the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided screenshot - everything looks ok.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer.